# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) Address_book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I tried to run my ruby address_book for testing on command line, I got this error, I don't know what's wrong with the code.

error

> address_bloc.rb:1:in `require_relative': >/Users/paul/address_bloc/controllers/menu_controller.rb:125: syntax error, >unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
>     from address_bloc.rb:1:in`'

-address_bloc.rb

```
require_relative 'controllers/menu_controller'


 menu = MenuController.new

 system "clear"
 puts "Welcome to AddressBloc!"
 menu.main_menu
```

-controllers/menu_controller.rb

```
require_relative "../models/address_book"

class MenuController

  attr_accessor :address_book

  def initialize
    @address_book = AddressBook.new
  end

  def main_menu
    puts "Main Menu - #{@address_book.entries.count} entries"
    puts "1 - View all entries"
    puts "2 - Create an entry"
    puts "3 - Search for an entry"
    puts "4 - Import entries from a CSV"
    puts "5 - Exit"
    print "Enter your selection: "

    selection = gets.to_i
    case selection
    when 1
      system "clear"
      view_all_entries
      main_menu
    when 2
      system "clear"
      create_entry
      main_menu
    when 3
      system "clear"
      search_entries
      main_menu
    when 4
      system "clear"
      read_csv
      main_menu
    when 5
      puts "Good-bye!"
      exit(0)
    else
      system "clear"
      puts "Sorry, that is not a valid input"
      main_menu
    end
  end

  def view_all_entries
     @address_book.entries.each do |entry|
       system "clear"
       puts entry.to_s

     entry_submenu(entry)
  end
     system "clear"
     puts "End of entries"
   end

   def create_entry

     system "clear"
     puts "New AddressBloc Entry"
     print "Name: "
     name = gets.chomp
     print "Phone number: "
     phone = gets.chomp
     print "Email: "
     email = gets.chomp

     @address_book.add_entry(name, phone, email)

     system "clear"
     puts "New entry created"
   end

   def search_entries
   end

   def read_csv
   end

   def entry_submenu(entry)
     puts "n - next entry"
     puts "d - delete_entry"
     puts "e - edit this entry"
     puts "m - return to main menu"

     selection = gets.chomp

     case selection
     when "n"
     when "d"
     when "e"
     when "m"
       system "clear"
       main_menu
     else
       system "clear"
       puts "#{selcetion} is not a valid input"
       entry_submenu(entry)
     end
  end
end
```

thank you

Comment: Typically that means a missing `end` but hard to say with unformatted code (``` doesn't work here)

Comment: You seriously need to reformat all the markdown of your question.

Comment: How to formate my code here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your question for readability. You're asking us to help you, but you didn't take the time to make it easy to help you. You can learn more about formatting the markdown by reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, which is available by clicking the `?` in the edit box.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I tried to run my ruby address_book for testing on command line, I got this error, I don't know what's wrong with the code.

Comment: As @MilesStanfield pointed out, your formatting is extremely bad. It is very impolite to ask others to work for you for free and not even spend the 2 seconds it takes to format your code properly, *especially* when missing an `end`, since simply formatting your code properly will just show you the problem.

Comment: sorry I just start programming, I will study learning formatting and refine my code.

Comment: This is a common error, from my experience and usually caused by an missing 'end'. However, if you want to find the missing 'end' easier, I would recommend you to format your code. If locally the code is formated, please paste it in a readable way so we can help you faster. I see above that you already found the missing 'end', but for the future I would recommend you this [article](https://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/10/20/how-to-fix-common-errors-when-testing-in-rspec/), especially if you are beginner. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your final `end` is closing `def entry_submenu(entry)` now you need a final `end` to close `class MenuController`

Like this:

```
require_relative "../models/address_book"

class MenuController
  attr_accessor :address_book

  def initialize
    @address_book = AddressBook.new
  end

  def main_menu
    puts "Main Menu - #{@address_book.entries.count} entries"
    puts "1 - View all entries"
    puts "2 - Create an entry"
    puts "3 - Search for an entry"
    puts "4 - Import entries from a CSV"
    puts "5 - View Entry Number n"
    puts "6 - Exit"
    print "Enter your selection: "

    selection = gets.to_i

    case selection
    when 1
      system "clear"
      view_all_entries
      main_menu
    when 2
      system "clear"
      create_entry
      main_menu
    when 3
      system "clear"
      search_entries
      main_menu
    when 4
      system "clear"
      read_csv
      main_menu
    when 5
      system "clear"
      display_entry_by_n
      main_menu
    when 6
      puts "Good-bye!"
      exit(0)
    else
      system "clear"
      puts "Sorry, that is not a valid input"
      main_menu
    end
  end


  def view_all_entries
    @address_book.entries.each do |entry|
      system "clear"
      puts entry.to_s

      entry_submenu(entry)
    end
    system "clear"
    puts "End of entries"
  end

  def create_entry

    system "clear"
    puts "New AddressBloc Entry"

    print "Name: "
    name = gets.chomp
    print "Phone number: "
    phone = gets.chomp
    print "Email: "
    email = gets.chomp

    @address_book.add_entry(name, phone, email)

    system "clear"
    puts "New entry created"
  end

  def display_entry_by_n
    system "clear"
    puts "Enter the entry number"
    print "Number:"
    selection = get.chomp.to_i
    if selection < @address_book.entries.size
      puts @address_book.entries[selection]
      puts "Press enter to return to main menu"
      gets.chomp
      system "clear"
    else
      puts "#{selection} is not a valid input"
      display_entry_by_n
    end
  end

  def search_entries
  end

  def read_csv
  end

  def entry_submenu(entry)
    puts "n - next entry"
    puts "d - delete_entry"
    puts "e - edit this entry"
    puts "m - return to main menu"

    selection = gets.chomp

    case selection
    when "n"
    when "d"
    when "e"
    when "m"
      system "clear"
      main_menu
    else
      system "clear"
      puts "#{selcetion} is not a valid input"
      entry_submenu(entry)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I added the 'end', it turns out more errors.
/Users/xxxx/address_bloc/controllers/menu_controller.rb:1:in `require_relative': /Users/paul/address_bloc/models/address_book.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
 from /Users/paul/address_bloc/controllers/menu_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 from address_bloc.rb:1:in `require_relative'
 from address_bloc.rb:1:in `<main>'

Comment: So now you are missing a closing `end` in `address_bloc/models/address_book.rb`. This is why formatting is so important. If you can't read your code because the indentation is poor, problems like these are hard to diagnose. Read your errors, they give you everything you need to diagnose what is wrong.